# How to use clip to only show the top 200px of an image?

Tags: html, css

I am dealing with Facebook profile images, and their height can vary a lot in size.
I am trying to use the clip CSS property to only get a maximum of 200px of the image. Here is what my CSS looks like:

```
.fixed {
  position: relative;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #555555;
}

.inner {
  position: absolute;
  clip: rect(0 0 200px 0);
}
```

Here is the actual HTML:

```
<div class="fixed"> 
  <div class="inner">
    <img src="large.jpg">
  </div> 
</div>
```

No image is being displayed. It works without the clip, but I only want the top 200px of an image.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.inner {
  overflow:hidden; 
  max-height:200px
}
```

It'll work on more browsers than `clip`.

Answer (score 2):

Your rect has no width so you won't see anything. Specify a value for the right dimension, for example, and you should be able to see it:

```
.inner {
  position: absolute;
  clip: rect(0px, 200px, 200px, 0px);
}
```

These values sometimes get confused with positioning values - think instead of where the sides of the rectangle would be based on the pixel values you assign - the left side is at 0, the right side is at 200, the top is at 0, the bottom is at 200.