# Setting the background color of the <video> element on IE 10

Tags: css, internet-explorer-10

I'm having a little bit of trouble with the video element on IE 10.

IE 10 seems to insist on adding in black to the background whenever the  element is set to be larger than the source video's width/height, whereas on Chrome, no background color is ever set.

Is there anyway to set a background color on the  element in IE 10? I've googled and googled, but cannot seem to find any answers.

Thanks!

Comment: Try background:transparent

Comment: Unfortunately no dice :(

Comment: How about - background-color:transparent, or if no dice, background-color:transparent !important;

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use clip to only show the top 200px of an image?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6382426/how-to-use-clip-to-only-show-the-top-200px-of-an-image)

Comment: Paul these are in no way duplicates, this is purely about the video element in IE 10, no amateur CSS stuff.

Comment: Setting background(-color) to transparent as suggested by @jack does not change the video background color.